# does <apex:relatedList" /> work to show user's child records?

Tags: apex

I created a simple page:

```
<apex:page controller="testController">
    <apex:relatedList subject="{!userId}" list="FeedSubscriptions"/>
</apex:page>
```

with simple controller:

```
public class testController {
    public String userId {get;set;}
    public testController() {
        userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    }
}
```

When I'm loading the page, It shows an error:
[image: error picture]

EntitySubscription(which is just the first standard child relationship that I found for user) is a standart object and it has a lookup to User object:

[image: EntitySubscription]

When I'm trying to do the same with account:

```
<apex:relatedList subject="{!accountId}" list="Opportunities"/>
```

It works perfectly.
Is there a way to show relatedList for user object on a custom VF page?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not every child relationship seems to work. The `subject` can be a User Id, but the `list`  has to compile.

Comment: Could you, please, give me a valid relationship to user Object? I tried before with custom lookup field from Account to User and got the same error. But for stackexchange, in order to avoid additional questions(like whether I checked child relationship name and so on) I decided to find any standard relationship.

Comment: There are a lot of them to test. I cannot confirm if any of them work, actually. There seems to be a gap between what is allowed in that component and what the `Schema` defines.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I created a custom field on Account with lookup to User and tried to show related records via this custom field - no success, the same error.